# Part of mesh distorted in object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]I have downloaded a character that I am traying to change. There are som distortions on the headmesh, but when I changes to edit mode they dissapear. Also the whole mesh is moved a bit i edit mode.
Another part of the mesh gets rotated in edit mode.
This makes it very hard to edit the modell and I would apriciate some help to solve this.
There are noe shape keys and no animations in the model.
I have Blender 3.4.1

[image]

Comment: Hello is it possible that you share the file? Or at least show a screenshot?

Comment: It's the head of the character PUBG SARA by GANJACKSON TONY at Scetchfab:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/pubg-sara-2e09bd40827d4ec7bdc47dcfccee5e47

Comment: And I now realize that the original file actually has an animation.

Comment: The original character doesn't have this distortion.

Comment: i'm not a subscriber to this site, if the object is copyright free, could you please share it through https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform

Comment: The blend-file with only the head is attached to the post.

Comment: Forgot about the license:
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is parented to an armature, you can see an *Armature* modifier in the *Modifiers* panel, for the moment you can't see the bones because they are disabled in the *Viewport Overlays* panel. Also note that you have 2 keyframes for your bones, if you bring the armature back to its rest pose your head mesh won't move anymore when you'll switch from *Object* to *Edit* mode.

[image]

Comment: I knew there was a simple sollution! I have learned something new today. Most appriciated, thanks!